# Is <92FB64J> an invalid XMLtag?

Tags: .net, xml, exception

> System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot start with the character "9", hexadecimal value 0x39

Is this because tags cannot start with numbers, or does this have to do with the xml encoding

Comment: The spec is your friend: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-NameStartChar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, element names [cannot start with a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Answer (score 3):

"XML element names can not start with a number or punctuation character."

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_elements.asp)

Comment: That isn't quite true. Some punctuation characters are allowed (underscore springs to mind). Avoid W3Schools, they are a terrible resource.

Comment: @David Dorward: The former is news to me, I'll have to look that up some more.  The latter, yes, I know that's true.  It was a moment of weakness :)

Answer (score 1):

They can not start with numbers (or the string "xml", for future reference).

Also, you should avoid the following characters:

```
. - :
```

In names.